# jquery focus and auto submit after last input is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two situation with jquery,

I have two text box(name, age), now what i need to do is auto focus the name onload while the age is disabled, once user key in an input on name, it become disabled and switch with age textbox(enable and focus). once the age textbox is filled, the jquery will auto submit it w/o any button

now first things is, I am able to disable and enable the textbox, but when i put ***document.name.focus()*** its not working, I mean, the focus is not working.second things is, i manage to do the auto submit using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name="age"]').blur(function(){
        if(this.value != ''){
            document.form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

so after the last textbox is filled, it will auto submit, but the problem is, I keep receive this error "Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\location" whenever i run it.

here is my code :

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('[name="age"]').blur(function(){
  if(this.value != ''){
   document.form.submit();
  }
 });
}); 

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name="name"]').blur(function() {
    var that = $('[name="age"]')[0];
    if (this.value != '') {
  this.focus();
      this.disabled = true;
      that.disabled = false;
    }
  });
});

function focusName(){ 
 var count = document.form.name.value.length + 1;
 if(count <= 8){
  document.form.name.focus();
 }else{
  document.form.age.focus();
 }
}

function focusAge(){
 var count = document.form.age.value.length + 1;
 if(count <= 10){
  document.form.age.focus()  
 }else{
  document.form.submit();
 }
}
</script>
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Information </legend>
<form action="receive.php" method="post" name="form">
 name : <input type="text" name="name" onKeyUp="focusName();" maxlength="8"><br>
 Age : <input typr="text" name="age" disabled onKeyUp="focusAge();" maxlength="3"><br>
 <!--input type="submit"-->
</form>
</fieldset>
```

please help!!.thanks.

Comment: I am not sure it makes that much sense what you described... When user does an input to name field it should switch with age field? That means user writes one letter and the name field gets disabled... and what if a user wants to do some edit on what he typed in? it's not possible if i get it right because the fields get submitted automatically when inputting something to age field.

Comment: yup, i notice that but that is what my customer want to, perhaps, there will be a condition before the textbox is switched, maybe a length measurement or somethings.

Answer (score 1):

Few tips : add some id on your textbox

**Example  :**

```
name : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onKeyUp="focusName();" maxlength="8"><br>
    Age : <input typr="text" id="age" name="age" disabled onKeyUp="focusAge();" maxlength="3">
```

Focus the name onload  (with JQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#name").focus();})
```

Auto submit your form :

```
$("form :input").focusout(function(){

   $(this).each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="" )
    {
      return false;
    }
  });
  $("form").submit();
});
```